# Xamarin iOS FlyoutNavigation is not initialized in some views

Tags: ios, xamarin, xamarin.ios, mvvmcross, navigationbar

I have a problem with FlyoutNavigation in my iOS project. My first view in both project Android/iOS is MenuViewModel, where I have init menu.
Im using MvvmCross (but old version v3.5.1).

In my iOS project in MenuView I have in ViewDidLoad() this:

```
var navigationController = new NavigationController();
_navigation = navigationController.Navigation;
View.AddSubview(_navigation.View);
this.AddChildViewController(_navigation);
```

where NavigationController Initialize FlyoutNavigation and looks like this:

```
public class NavigationController
{
    private FlyoutNavigationController _navigation;
    public FlyoutNavigationController Navigation { get; private set; }
    private UIViewController _mainView;
    //private UIViewController _purchasesView;
    private UIViewController _ordersView;
    private UIViewController _profileView;
    private UIViewController _writeUsView;
    private UIViewController _aboutView;
    private UIViewController _tradeTermsView;
    private UIViewController _contactView;

    public NavigationController()
    {
        _navigation = new FlyoutNavigationController();
        Initialize();
        Navigation = _navigation;
    }

    private void Initialize()
    {
        var textProvider = Mvx.Resolve<IMvxTextProviderBuilder>().TextProvider;
        var profileName = Mvx.Resolve<IMvxTextProviderBuilder>().TextProvider.GetText("XXX", "MenuViewModel", "Profile");

        _navigation.Position = FlyOutNavigationPosition.Left;
        //_navigation.View.Frame = UIScreen.MainScreen.Bounds;
        _navigation.NavigationTableView.BackgroundColor = UIColor.FromRGBA(0, 0, 0, 240);

        var profileMenuItem = new StyledStringElement(profileName)
        {
            BackgroundColor = UIColor.FromRGBA(0, 0, 0, 240),
            TextColor = UIColor.White,
            Font = UIFont.PreferredBody,
            Image = UIImage.FromBundle("Icons/Profile")
        };

        Mvx.Resolve<IMvxMessenger>().Subscribe<UserProfileChangedMessage>(x =>
        {
            profileMenuItem.Caption = $"{x.Profile.FirstName} {x.Profile.LastName}";
        }, MvxReference.Strong);

        // Create the menu:
        _navigation.NavigationRoot = new RootElement("Navigation")
        {
            new Section("")
            {
                new StyledStringElement (textProvider.GetText("XXX", "MenuViewModel", "MainPage")) {
                  BackgroundColor = UIColor.FromRGBA(0,0,0,240),
                  TextColor = UIColor.White,
                  Font = UIFont.PreferredBody,
                  //Font = UIFont.FromName("Lato-Black", 16f),
                  Image = UIImage.FromBundle("Icons/MainPage")
                },
                  new StyledStringElement (textProvider.GetText("XXX", "MenuViewModel", "Orders")) {
                    BackgroundColor = UIColor.FromRGBA(0,0,0,240),
                    TextColor = UIColor.White,
                    Font = UIFont.PreferredBody,
                    Image = UIImage.FromBundle("Icons/MyShopping")
                },
                profileMenuItem,
                new StyledStringElement (textProvider.GetText("XXX", "MenuViewModel", "WriteUs")) {
                    BackgroundColor = UIColor.FromRGBA(0,0,0,240),
                    TextColor = UIColor.White,
                    Font = UIFont.PreferredBody,
                  Image = UIImage.FromBundle("Icons/WriteUs")
                },
                 new StyledStringElement (textProvider.GetText("XXX", "MenuViewModel", "About")) {
                BackgroundColor = UIColor.FromRGBA(0,0,0,240),
                Font = UIFont.PreferredBody,
                TextColor = UIColor.White
                },
                new StyledStringElement(textProvider.GetText("XXX", "MenuViewModel", "TradeTerms")){
                BackgroundColor = UIColor.FromRGBA(0,0,0,240),
                Font = UIFont.PreferredBody,
                TextColor = UIColor.White
                },
                new StyledStringElement(textProvider.GetText("XXX", "MenuViewModel", "Contact")){
                BackgroundColor = UIColor.FromRGBA(0,0,0,240),
                Font = UIFont.PreferredBody,
                TextColor = UIColor.White
                }
            }
        };

        // Create an array of UINavigationControllers that correspond to your
        // menu items:
        _mainView = ViewHelper.GetViewFromViewModel<MainViewModel>();
        _aboutView = ViewHelper.GetViewFromViewModel<AboutViewModel>();
        _contactView = ViewHelper.GetViewFromViewModel<ContactViewModel>();
        _profileView = ViewHelper.GetViewFromViewModel<ProfileViewModel>();
        //_purchasesView = ViewHelper.GetViewFromViewModel<PurchasesViewModel>();
        _ordersView = ViewHelper.GetViewFromViewModel<OrdersViewModel>();
        _tradeTermsView = ViewHelper.GetViewFromViewModel<TradeTermsViewModel>();
        _writeUsView = ViewHelper.GetViewFromViewModel<WriteUsViewModel>();

        _navigation.ViewControllers = new UIViewController[]
        {
            _mainView, /*_purchasesView,*/ _ordersView, _profileView, _writeUsView, _aboutView, _tradeTermsView, _contactView
        };

        var messenger = Mvx.Resolve<IMvxMessenger>();
        var menuState = Mvx.Resolve<IMenuState>();

        messenger.SubscribeOnMainThread<MenuClickMessage>(x =>
        {
            // Show the navigation view
            if (_navigation.IsOpen)
            {
                _navigation.HideMenu();
                menuState.Switch();
            }
            else
            {
                _navigation.ShowMenu();
                menuState.Switch();
            }
        }, MvxReference.Strong);
    }

}
```

Navigation initialize first ViewModel and View - MainView/MainViewModel...

My problem is when I'm using menu items in navigation its working everythink well... but when I have for example in OrderView button with ICommand where is ShowViewModel() so when I click on this button and my view change on TradeTermsView here my FlyoutNavigation doesnt work... Navigation not appears something like its not initialized here I dont know...Navigation Button here is normal but when I click on it Navigation doesnt show... but when I click in MainView in Navigation on TradeTerms and there in TradeTerms Navigation works. Its seems Navigation working only in Views which I click from Navigation but not from ShowViewModel<>() command.

My another problem with FlyoutNavigation is when Im clicking on Navigation button show on and off and after Im click on item in CollectionView and Im moving to this view so there is some free spaces on bottom and top in this view...It seems like Navigation give here some frames moreover... But when I start app again and click on item w/o clicking on Navigation button so view looks normal.

Example here: 
[image]